# Start and stop redmine server without root access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, redmine

I'm using Redmine 2.2.0 in Linux environment. My Ruby version is 1.9.3 (x86_64-linux) and Rails version is 3.2.9. Currently I'm using `ctlscript.sh` to start and stop my server but it will work only if I log in as root user. I need to start and stop my Redmine server without root access. Is it possible? What are the changes that I need to make? Can any one please help?

Comment: give the redmine folder permissions to the user you're trying to use.